# Rails 5 Stopped Validating Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a rails 5 project that I've been working on since January and today I noticed that I was able to create a child record without specifying the parent. This is rather alarming since I verified that I am using rails 5.1.2 along with ruby 2.4.1. The site is still in development. I opened up rails console and tested a few of my other models that should have parent validations (should validate by default in rails 5) and those records were created too without the associations.

This makes no sense. I do know that this was working at some point. The largest change was made earlier this week when I added in the gem "paperclip" for file uploads. Does anyone have any suggestions or have any ideas on what to check?

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    require 'csv'

    include SendGrid
    belongs_to :admin, optional: true
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :return
    has_many :order_shipments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :order_addresses, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :order_comments, dependent: :destroy


     ......

end




class OrderShipment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :order
end
```

I've added the following code to my development.rb and production.rb environments and it appears to resolve the issue as if it is overriding something that paperclip could be doing.

```
config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

However, I think this code should go in application.rb but "config" is not initialized so I get the following error when doing so:

```
undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how your models are setup and what you ran to create these models? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also, if you create a new project from scratch do you see this?

Comment: I'm assuming this a **belongs_to** parent relationship.  In rails 5.X a belongs to became required be default. But paperclip could be doing something different then a **belongs_to** Can you post some code of your model?

Comment: @MichaelDeering I've added some code. Your assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly offtopic: I **strongly advise against using reserved words as associations** such as `has_one :return` since you will get into conflicts eventually.

In this case you won't be able to do something like:

```
def some_method
  # ...some actions
  return # say, you wanted to return the association.
end
```

If you want to set Rails config variables in `production.rb` or `development.rb` you have to use `Rails.application.config.` instead of just `config.` in those files.

In Rails 5 `belongs_to` should be validated by default unless you specify `optional: true` for the association. So in this case your association `belongs_to :admin` will not be validated. If you have issues with a different association, please update your answer with rails console output when trying to create, say, `Order` object without any other associations and I will try and update my answer.